# Javascript library does not return global variable/definition

Tags: javascript

I just want to ask for help regarding my problem, I have an external JS library and currently it is working when it's inside the  tag in html, however when I try to incorporate it to my factory function you can see in the network that it has been read but when you try to use the global variable it is undefined, global variable is FlowchartLayout.

This is the snippet of the external JS library, I tried to make it an UMD module

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('b'));
  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(['b'], function (b) {
      return (root.returnExportsGlobal = factory(b));
    });
  } else {
    // Global Variables
    root.returnExportsGlobal = factory(root.b);
  }
}(this, function (b) {
    'use strict';

    function FlowchartLayout() {
        go.Layout.call(this);
        this._angle = 90;
        this._nodeSpacing = 40; // between nodes in same layer
        this._layerSpacing = 40; // between nodes in different layers
        this._laneProperty = "lane"; // name of data property that identifies lane as a unique number or a string
        this._laneComparer = null; // function for sorting FlowchartLanes
        this._reset();
    }
    go.Diagram.inherit(FlowchartLayout, go.Layout);
        
       /*The rest of the code of FlowchartLayout*/

    return FlowchartLayout;

}));
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: How are you incorporating it into your factory function?